# Div Overflow Scrolling in fixed footer

Tags: html, css

I am trying to incorporate a scroll on content with footer being sticky. I want as the screen size reduces (height reduces) the content should be scrolled not cut off or visible.

I have read most of the threads and tried min-height, max-height, overflow, overflow-y auto, scroll, !important.

Still, I am unable to achieve this.

Please have a look at http://vishsid73.github.io/scroll/scroll.html
the code is at http://github.com/vishsid73/scroll

Please have a look and guide.

Comment: there is nothing to scroll.....

Comment: @DCdaz: If you reduce the size of window I want the content to scrollable. (reduce the height of window)

Comment: Still looking for a sloution

Answer (score 0):

Set height in css as well like

```
height:200px;
max-height:200px;
overflow-y: scroll;
```

Comment: it works just inside the div but I want to scroll above the footer that is bottom - 161px. How to do that